# QAC messages: What is 5703?

Tags: standards

I've looked in http://products.prqa.com/Unix/Linux/QAC_PRQAF/QAC-9.4.1-ReleaseNotes.pdf and it doesn't feature. Any ideas where this is defined? It's also not defined in the **PRQA** framework.

**Update:**

This is for **MISRA** compliance.

Answer (score 0):

It's depends of set of rules which was used for analysis. First of all please ensure yourself is it a **CERT-C**, **MISRA** or e.g **CWEC**